# Error: argumemt is not a character vector inside Shiny app with reactive variable

Tags: r, shiny

I'm receiving this error message when making selections on my first Shiny app.

Here's a sample data frame which the code below draws on:

```
# generate sample data
sample_data <- data.frame(
  Device = c("Desktop", "Desktop", "Desktop", "Tablet", "Tablet", "Tablet", "Mobile", "Mobile", "Mobile"),
  Channel = c("Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "Affiliate", "Affiliate", "Affiliate", "Paid", "Paid", "Paid"),
  LandingPageGroup = c("Example.Com", "Example.Com", "Example.Com", "AbTest", "AbTest", "AbTest", "Custom", "Custom", "Custom"),
  Date_Range = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-30"), by = 1),
  Sessions = ceiling(rnorm(90, mean = 3000, sd = 300)),
  Registrations = ceiling(rnorm(90, mean = 800, sd = 100)),
  Conversion1 = ceiling(rnorm(90, mean = 400, sd = 50)),
  Conversion2 = ceiling(rnorm(90, mean = 20, sd = 7))
)
```

In ui.R I have this sidebar with inputs:

```
  sidebarLayout(
    ## Sidebar inputs here
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("device",
                  "Device", 
                  c("Desktop", "Tablet", "Mobile")),
      selectInput("channel",
                  "Channel", 
                  c("Organic", "Affiliate", "Paid")),
      selectInput("landing",
                  "Landing Page Group", 
                  c("Example.Com", "AbTest", "Custom"))
    ),
    ## main panel output here
    mainPanel(
        # Create a new row for the table.
        fluidRow(
          DT::dataTableOutput("table")
          ),
        br(), br()
    )
  )
```

Then, in server.R here's the beginning of my app up to the code that I think is relevant:

(sample data frame defined above, before the function(input, output))

```
    library(dplyr)
    sample_txdata <- tbl_df(sample_txdata)

function(input, output) {

  # create reactive set of data with filters applied by user
  filtered <- reactive({
    sample_txdata %>%
      filter(Device == input$device,
             Channel == input$channel,
             LandingPageGroup == input$landing
        )
    })

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
      filtered() %>% {code block that does stuff to the data}
```

The app works in that the table loads up and renders fine. Except as soon as I make a selection in one of the 3 input filters I get the above error and the table disappears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data your provide, it is not a shiny problem, but a "sample data" problem. The select inputs will work, but only for the following combinations:

```
unique(sample_txdata[, 1:3])
```

Case 1: `Desktop   Organic      Example.Com` is the default of your select inputs, that i why you initially see data within the table.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I figured out how to build a sample data frame with unique combinations of all data but the problem persists. Going to delete and repost a new. Thanks all the same